# Collecting Radio Logs for Nexus 5 Using QXDM

Tags: android, diagnostics

I need rrc messages exchanged on my device(Rooted Nexus 5, Android 5.0.1). I am planning to use QXDM for collecting Radio logs. Google tells me that for using QXDM i need to enter diagnostic mode in my nexus (I have never used Qxdm before). Please help me how to enter diagnostic mode for getting radio logs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006903/android-diagnostic-mode-how-to-enable-it looks pretty close to your question.

Comment: I have seen that question but there is no proper answer for enabling diag mode @wolendranh

Answer (score 1):

To enable "Diag" mode on your Nexus 5 you will have to flash a custom kernel.

Please see the following pages from xda-developers.com.

[Hybrid Kernel](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/aosp-kernel-hybrid-3-0-nightly-builds-05-apr.2918578/)
[Enable Diag on Nexus 5](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/dev-enable-diagnostic-mode.2535478/)